# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

Tags: blogger, adsense, adsense-api

how to solve
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

[image]

Error link: http://dominicdomu.blogspot.in/

Comment: domain  banned from Google AdSense